# filtrar lista de listas por si el elemento inicial empieza por un numero

Tags: python

Estoy intentando filtrar el wickcionario en español y estoy teniendo problemas para extraer las definiciones del xml.
He conseguido separar el texto de las definiciones pero hay muchas separaciones que viene con comandos del xml no utiles para mi, lo único que me vale son aquellos textos que comiencen con un numero(en concreto es un ; y un numero pero la separación se ha hecho por ;).
Extrapolando el problema seria sacar de la siguiente lista de listas solo las que comiencen por un número.
El código con el que estoy probando ahora  con el comando filter es:

```
soloem=[]

arrayprueba=[["2:acuerdo de firmas","de firmas","4holam"],["casa2","3c"]]

 
    
def dua(lama):
    try:
       if (lama[0].isdigit()):
         return True 
    except:
         print("algo no salio como toca")
soloem=list(filter(lambda ta:ta.dua(),arrayprueba))
```

es uno de los muchos intentos también he probado con for anidados pero se repiten todas las definiciones, el resutado que debería mostrar en variables soloem sería
[["2:acuerdo de firmas,4holam],[3c].

La lista de listas es solo un ejemplo, en el xml de wikipedia hay mas de 101 millones de  "posibles definiciones" muchas de ellas basura como seperadores de linea del xml o partes del formato que usa wikimedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías probar esto:

```
soloem = [[cadena for cadena in lista if len(cadena) and cadena[0].isdigit()] for lista in arrayprueba]
```

Esto crearía una lista, con listas de cadenas dentro, donde sólo se agregarán la cadenas donde el primer caracter sea un número.

Espero te sirva!

Comment: muchísimas gracias resuelve mi problema descrito.